# Android Studio can't resolve any Java objects but builds and deploys APKs that run

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My IDE editor is full of errors, it cannot resolve Java objects of any type, even something as basic as a String. In spite of the huge mass of red lines and error flags all over my code, it still builds and deploys working APKs. Of course if I get a real error I will never know as it will be buried by all the other errors.

Here are some imports that Android Studio cannot resolve:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
```

I have tried uninstalling as much as I could find and re-installing, and trying to match the correct gradle components (the part which I find most difficult and confusing) for 4.2.0. Most of these attempts were based upon posts of what looked like similar problems from this site. They were often several years old.

I use the gradle wrapper. I also have IntelliJ installed and do not know if that is causing the problems. It hasn't for the last couple of years. I am at a total loss. Anyone have some idea what is going on?

Is there a way to clean out EVERYTHING without deleting my projects and restart?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that usually help in situations like this:

1. *File* -> *Invalidate Caches/Restart*
2. If (1) does not help (wait for all the indexing to finish) you can also quit AndroidStudio and then delete the `.idea` folder in your project. If your project is set up with gradle, this does not hurt, as you only lose some minor project related IDE configs (maybe back-up the folder if you are unsure.

AndroidStudio (or IntelliJ in general) screws up its caches and indexes sometimes. This seems to be happening more often lately. The two approaches above mitigate that by making sure all caches and indexes are rebuilt for the project.

Comment: I have tried many things (including uninstall and reinstall), the above being one of them. I will try again in that order and see if it helps.

Comment: Alas it did not work. Added examples of JDK class imports that are not resolved. But thanks for the help. Its ugly seeing all those red squiggles in my code.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with IntelliJ?

Comment: strange enough - no! Intellij works fine. In Android Studio the problem is NOT with Android modules but Java modules and of course any references to methods and classes in the Java modules. My settings file has an error on new File(...) for setting module location (didnt before) - File not understood. I cant make any sense out if it. It has to be a major Android bug associated with 4.2.0. I am going to see if I can bring back pre 4.2.0.

Comment: Reverted back to Android 4.1.3 and all the problems went away. This used gradle 4.1.3 and the gradle wrapper gradle-6.5-bin.zip. I don't know whether I should be happy or sad. This is the first time an AS studio upgrade has caused a problem since WAY back when AS first came out. Wonder what happens if I try and use newer versions of gradle that 4.2.1 requires and newer gradle wrappers? Dare I?